# Resync Azure Active Directory after Domain change

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory

I have synced Active Directory with Azure Active Directory.

However after I did this, I setup my custom domain. Yes I know, I did this in the wrong order.

My question: Is there a way to resync Active Directory and Azure Active Directory so that all the usernames can be updated with the new domain?

Answer (score 0):

Open your power shell and type

```
Get-MsolDirSyncFeatures -Feature EnableSoftMatchOnUpn
```

Soft match means you get an bidirectional snych. If this feature is not active within you setup you need to activate it first with

```
Set-MsolDirSyncFeature -Feature EnableSoftMatchOnUpn -Enable $true
```

After this a forced delta synch should deliver the wanted results in the hybrid config. 
IF you have colliding objects afterwards, you could take a look into here.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2523192/user-names-in-office-365-azure-or-intune-don-t-match-the-on-premises-u

All Accounts could be synched and combined again without any problems. There is also a error correction in your azure active directory admin interface.